# User Input numbers into List with search for duplicates

Tags: java

The code is based on a List with user input. It then displays the list and asks for input y/n. If yes it displays Enter and lets you input numbers separated by commas. Which works fine.

However, after the while loop it starts the collections.frequency which I don't understand yet. It only works if the numbers are input one by one like 12 then hit enter the input more numbers until pressed n. That breaks the loop. And displays the list with duplicates.

However, it doesn't work if the numbers are input all in one line at once like so: 12,23,55, and so forth. It will not find nor display duplicates. Only what's in the list. I find that very cumbersome to have to input the numbers one at a time. Can someone help me to change the code so I can input numbers all at once, then hit enter and still have the code search for duplicates and display the duplicates at the end.

```
package Input_Array_From_User;
import java.util.*;
public class Input_Array {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Current list is " + list);
        System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
        if (stdin.next().startsWith("y")) {
            System.out.println("Enter : ");
            list.add(stdin.next());
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    System.out.println("\nExample 2 - Count all with frequency");
    Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(list);
    for (String temp : uniqueSet) {
        System.out.println(temp + " shows that many times : " + Collections.frequency(list, temp));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nick, your question is hard to read.. (one big blob of text) could you help us with some formatting and show us some code please?  Please read the [ask] page for hints

Comment: Nick the code does paste into the question textbox, try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the numbers all at once separated by *whitespace* and hit Enter after you finish:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

To do that, you'd have to stop asking if the user wants to add more at each iteration, though. To know when to stop, you can ask the user to inform the number of elements they want to input before starting the loop and the stopping the loop when you reach that number.

The code would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = stdin.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        list.add(stdin.next());
    }
    System.out.println("\nExample 2 - Count all with frequency");
    Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(list);
    for (String temp : uniqueSet) {
        System.out.println(temp + " shows that many times : " + Collections.frequency(list, temp));
    }
}
```

An example input would be:

```
5
1 2 2 4 5
```

And the corresponding output would be:

```
Example 2 - Count all with frequency
1 shows that many times : 1
2 shows that many times : 2
4 shows that many times : 1
5 shows that many times : 1
```

If you want to use a custom delimiter such as `,` check the method `useDelimiter()` from `Scanner`.

Comment: Hi Anderson Vieira, Thanks alot. The code works great that way you showed me. I should've known that since I know the for loop. Shame on me. Again Thanks. I just had to change the variable "num" to "n" to make it work. No big deal. I also added this line: Enter the amount of numbers you want to input: so any user is prompted to input numbers.

Comment: Now all I need to learn is how to make this code work in my android phone?